# What is a good database design (schema) for a attendance database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to make a application for keeping attendance for a relative's martial arts studio. I've tried looking around for some similar examples, but I couldn't find any specific or clear enough ones for this kind of application.

At the moment, I am using two tables, one for keeping student information, students(id, first_name, last_name, email, ...), and another table for attendance by the weeks in a year, attendance(id, week_1, week_2, week_3, ...). I am trying to change it to keep attendance by days instead, but can't seem to think of a good approach since I'm still kind of new to MySQL.

I am trying to make it so it is possible to see the attendance in a calendar-like format. It probably would be bad to just make columns for 365 days... and same with having a table for each month. I've noticed some similar applications just keep track of the dates, and store that in the database. Would this approach be better? Or, is there some other better approach to designing this kind of database? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO The  best answer is given in DBA SE forum here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52140/194268

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Attendance should have id, student_id and date. This is all you need to record when students attended. if you want to know how many students attended on a specific date (and who) you run a query for that specific date or date range.

You could also create a lesson table, in which case the attendance table would be 
id, student_id and lesson_id
the lesson table could be
id, held_on_date

unless you need to add more columns to the lesson table, I think it is overkill.

Answer (score 24):

In martial arts, instructors are students too -- so the `Instructor` table is sub-typed to the `Student` table. All common fields are in the `Student` table and only columns specific to instructors are in the `Instructor` table.

The `Art` table has list of arts that the school offers (judo, karate ...).

The school may have several rooms, these are listed in the `Room` table.

`ClassSchedule` describes the published schedule of classes that the school offers.

Attendance is captured in the `Attendance` table.

One row in the `Calendar` table is one calendar day (date). The table has date-properties like `DayOfWeek`, `MonthName`, `MonthNumberInYear` etc.

One row in the `TimeTable` is one minute of a day, like 7:05.

Calendar and TimeTable allow for easy attendance reporting by date/time, for example

```
-- Attendance of judo morning classes
-- for the first three months of the year 2010
-- by day of a week (Sun, Mon, Tue, ..)
select
    DayOfWeek
  , count(1) as Students
from ClassSchedule as a
join Calendar      as b on b.CalendarId = a.CalendarId
join TimeTable     as c on c.TimeID     = a.StartTimeId
join Attendance    as d on d.ClassId    = a.ClassID
join Art           as e on e.ArtId      = a.ArtID
where ArtName = 'judo'
  and Year    = 2010
  and MonthNumberInYear between 1 and 3
  and PartOfDay = 'morning'
group by DayOfWeek ;
```

[image]

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: The date table is a datawarehousing technique. That's probably very confusing to a person who is, self-admittedly, very new to mySQL. I strongly recommend against a calendar dimension when a normal date column will be just fine in a transactional database.

Comment: And a time dimension... what the hell are you trying to do this newbie?

Comment: @Stephanie -- So, how well do you know Daniel and what makes you think that he can not understand this?

Comment: @Stephanie -- True, datetime columns would be just fine in the `ClassSchedule` table. Using `Calendar` and `TimeTable` is simply a technique for removing date and time functions from the WHERE clause of a query, and yes used frequently in data-warehousing.

Comment: The OP can't figure out a very simple data structure. Simple to us maybe but this is all new to him, since he actually SAYS SO IN THE OP.

Comment: Your query example and ER diagram were easy to understand and very informative. The application isn't going to have that much complexity, but I think it will be helpful if these additional features are added later on. Thank you, Damir.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic...hey what about attendance as varchar bits.....i.e 011111110....

Comment: @akp, Not in a DB, bit-mapping techniques are appropriate for lower-level languages down to assembler, but not a good idea in a DB. Technically, it does not satisfy definition of a relation (one value per field), so does not even make it to 1NF.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic as your attendance table is storing pair of `studentid` and `classid` so lets suppose we have 60 students and all of them are present on a particular day, so we need to store 60 values (pair of studentids and classids) to attendance table? and what if we have 3 `arts` and 60 students is each one of them then attendance table will have 180 entries on a particular day...?

Comment: @Deepak And...? 10 million rows of that table is ~ 0.2 GB (index included).

Comment: @DamirSudarevic ohk, I got your point But just to ensure, is there any other more efficient way to track the attendance?

Comment: @DamirSudarevic you said `10 million rows of that table is ~ 0.2 GB (index included)` is this a prediction or their is some method to calculate the size...?

Answer (score 2):

Step back a little, you have two types of entities:

- a person [like a student]
- events [like a class]

Think of any entity as something that exists in the real world.

And one relationship

- attendance

A relationship is just that, an association between entities, and often has **time** data associated with it or other types of **measures**.

So without thinking too hard, you should have 3 database tables:

- attendee [E]
- class [E]
- attendance [R]

E = entity, R = relationship

If you find yourself duplicating data in one of the entity tables, this is a good sign that this entity requires a "sub-model".  In some places this is called "don't repeat yourself" or DRY and for entity relational modeling, this is called "data normalization".

Remember, there's overhead in both time and code to build a more elaborate schema.   So consider starting simple [3 tables] and refactoring away redundancy.