# DB design for daily attendance

Tags: database-design

what logic should I use to implement a daily basis attendance management system? (daily basis means "taking attendance once a day"), what kind of dbms structure should I follow? should I use trigger to get all the students for a particular day whenever a particular day is getting created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good database design (schema) for a attendance database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939764/what-is-a-good-database-design-schema-for-a-attendance-database)

Comment: Not really, since I'm trying to create a list of students on a particular date and then check their status, since I'm getting the default page, and also facing issue when creating a trigger and running it on the condition of date getting created