# Gathering data from two different tables, Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have two separate tables that represent student attendance for two weeks, respectively.  I want to be generate two columns that break down the attendance by week for each of the students.  If a student was present multiple times a week, the number of times present should be added.  Also, if a student was present in one week and not the next, it would get 1 for the month present (assuming it was only present once) and and 0 for the one absent.  I have tried to multiple variations of count() and joins but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The following is a truncated fiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36a6e0

Here is a sample of what I am trying to achive:

`Name  |  CurrWeek |  LastWeek`

`Paula |     0     |      2`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, which is not a free code writing or homework service.  You should at least also show us what the expected output is.

Comment: mysql and sql server both are diffrent, please retag

Comment: You should add your attempts and the desired output to get a better solution.

Comment: @ArsmanAhmad, "add attempts" as in a union?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Not homework.  Excuse me for not originally including enough info, this is my first post.  Just added expected output.

Comment: This is fairly bad design, because to get the answer you want, we'll have to do a full outer join between the two tables.  A better approach, since this is isn't homework, is to have a single master table of all students.  Then, you could easily left join that to each of your two attendance tables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen.  That's a good way of comparing.  However, what would the left join be on?  This is especially tricky since for given week, a student can have 0, 1 or multiple days of attendance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join and count and for merging both result set need union

```
select T1.name,T1.currentwk,T2.lasttwk from 
    (
    select name,count(id) as currentwk from currentWeek

    group by name
    ) as T1

     left  join 
     (

     select name,count(id) as lasttwk from lastWeek

    group by name
       ) as T2
       on T1.name=T2.name

     union 
     select T2.name,T1.currentwk,T2.lasttwk from 
    (
    select name,count(id) as currentwk from currentWeek

    group by name
    ) as T1

     right  join 
     (

     select name,count(id) as lasttwk from lastWeek

    group by name
       ) as T2
       on T1.name=T2.name
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36a6e0/25

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'll be looking into this.

Comment: How would I be able to add additional tables to this.  For instance, if I add one more table for a total of three:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fea08

Comment: @MiddleZ I think you need proper knowledge on database design rather adding more and more table , for attendance related design you can follow this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939764/what-is-a-good-database-design-schema-for-a-attendance-database

Comment: Thanks for that.  However, I'm not designing this db, rather am working with what I have.  My db is more complex than just attendance.  This is a mock db that I made to simplify the data that my db contains.  Your example for 2 tables was helpful and I'd be grateful if you could explain for three tables.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**For 2 Tables**

```
Select name, max(current_week) current_week, max(last_week) as last_week
    From (
    Select name, count(1) as current_week, 0 as last_week from currentWeek group by name
    union all
    Select name, 0 as current_week, count(1) as last_week from lastWeek group by name
    ) x
    group by name
```

**For 3 Tables**

```
Select name, max(current_week) current_week, max(last_week) as last_week, max(third_week) as third_week
    From (
    Select name, count(1) as current_week, 0 as last_week, 0 as thrid_week from currentWeek group by name
    union all
    Select name, 0 as current_week, count(1) as last_week, 0 as thrid_week from lastWeek group by name
    union all
    Select name, 0 as current_week, 0 as last_week, count(1) as thrid_week from thirdWeek group by name
    ) x
    group by name
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  How would I be able to add additional tables to this.  For instance, if I have three tables instead of two:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b847a

Comment: You can add any no. of table in the inline view and add those column in outer query
added the 3rd table in the answer