# What's a good DB design schema for advanced attendance?

Tags: mysql, database-design

First off, I did read this post [What is a good database design (schema) for a attendance database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939764/what-is-a-good-database-design-schema-for-a-attendance-database) but it doesn't fit my needs and I'm struggling to adapt it to my scenario.

I will try to explain in brief.

Let's take a school (sort of):

- School has courses with a starting and an ending date
- Students can be "subscribed" to multiple courses
- A subscription doesn't necessary start from the beginning nor ending at the end of the course.
- The student can be attended punctually (independently of the subscription) or transferred punctually in an another course.

I came with this design in mind:

[image]

My idea:

- When transferring punctually a student, I can change the `course_id`
- I can create an attendee without `subscription_id`, on demand

My problem:
With this design, It's seems over complicated and to see who's coming to a course, I see only two solutions.

1. Count the number of subscription, add the number of attendees present, remove the number of attendees absent.
2. Use a queue worker to create all the attendees and count the number of present attendee.

What would it be the easier way or what better schema could I use?

Comment: What does `transferring punctually a student` mean?

Comment: @MatBailie sorry for my bad english. Let's say you're subscribed to math every monday. So every monday you go to your math course, but next week, for some reason, the administror changed you for the french course, still the monday, no math but french, just like that. Then the week after, you go back to your general subscription : math

Comment: Implement a calendar style structure.  Instead of setting up repeating patterns, explicitly record who is going to what course on what date.  When moving a student from one course to another, change each and every relevant entry, like on your phone when it asks "just this occurrence, or all future occurrences".  Then, in that calendar, you can record whether they attended.  Or have a second calendar of what they actually did, and have queries that can compare Actual vs Planned.

Comment: @MatBailie `explicitly record who is going to what course on what date` If I understand you correctly, it would mean that a user would have to create manually each of the `attendee` records for the year or a queue worker to create them all. In a standard use case, students will participate between 6 months to a year in a course. And I **must** track the "from" "to" date, so we can fill the gap and optimize the number of subscriptions in the year. (You don't need to have pre-required to be attended. It's for all level)